# Porting code using sizeof() from C++ to PHP

Tags: php, c++, porting, sizeof, struct

I have some C++ code (segment seen below), I need to convert this to another language (namely PHP). The code, as seen, uses structs, which PHP doesn't do. I know I can "kind of" emulate structs through objects/arrays, however, this isn't the same. That is not my main problem though. I need a way to implement the `sizeof()` function found in C++ (since PHP's `sizeof()` function just counts the number of elements in an array/object).

```
typedef unsigned long Offset;
typedef unsigned long Size;

struct Location {
    Offset offset;
    Size size;
};

struct Header {
    unsigned long magic;
    unsigned long version;
    struct Location elements;
    struct Location ids;
    struct Location strings;
    struct Location integers;
    struct Location decimals;
    struct Location files;
};
int Build() {
    Header theheader;
    theheader.magic = *((unsigned long*)"P3TF");
    theheader.version = 272;
    theheader.elements.offset = sizeof(theheader);
    theheader.elements.size = element_offset;
    theheader.ids.offset = ((theheader.elements.offset + theheader.elements.size + 15) / 16) * 16;
    theheader.ids.size = ids_offset;
    theheader.strings.offset = ((theheader.ids.offset + theheader.ids.size + 15) / 16) * 16;
    theheader.strings.size = string_offset;
    theheader.integers.offset = ((theheader.strings.offset + theheader.strings.size + 15) / 16) * 16;
    theheader.integers.size = 0;
    theheader.decimals.offset = ((theheader.integers.offset + theheader.integers.size + 15) / 16) * 16;
    theheader.decimals.size = 0;
    theheader.files.offset = ((theheader.decimals.offset + theheader.decimals.size + 15) / 16) * 16;
    theheader.files.size = file_offset;
    theheader.padding[0] = 0;
    theheader.padding[1] = 0;
    fwrite(&theheader, 1, sizeof(theheader), file_handle);
}
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whyd do you need a field that describes the size of the struct?  The answer to that may help provide the answer to the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth this is usually done for serialization purposes, so that you can write a struct directly to a file or a socket. I could be way off though.

Comment: @Chris: I know what is *often* the case; but this question can't be answered until the OP tells us what *is* the case...

Comment: This is done for the purpose of writing to file. Essentially the code above is only the writing the header (in this case it is 64bytes). In order to get write the rest of the file properly, I need to find offsets for different bits of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply sum all sizes of the objects in the array or object. However, that still only gets the length of strings, etc. If you want the actual size of the binary representation of the object, you'll have to do some additional math, such as converting all ints to 32 bits (or 64) and appending a null byte to all UTF-8 strings. If you're using charsets, do make sure that they are single-byte or at least measurable in bytes.

PHP does not have a function that checks the memory size of an object.

Comment: But what purpose does this achieve?

Comment: I suppose you could use it to measure how much bytes C++ would have used.

Comment: That is quite an interesting approach to take, albeit, a lengthy one I think. I'll see what I can do, however, so far it looks like it would be easier to just use cgi-bin to achieve the same thing.

Comment: That is correct. Languages like PHP are designed to avoid having to do memory stuff, which is what you want to do.

Comment: Indeed, Cheers for this anyway! I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously recreating `sizeof` from C will be a difficult feat, as C is statically-typed and, traditionally, `sizeof` is evaluated at run-time by the compiler. PHP is also pretty quiet about its memory usage.

One method of dynamically grabbing the size of an object is to use `memory_get_usage` ([official PHP reference](http://us.php.net/memory_get_usage)) before and after the allocation of the object in question. Of course, you'll run into some fun calculations when you compare the two memory usage values, as storing the values into variables will allocate memory also.

This is a pretty shaky method of recreating `sizeof`, but if it works it works.

Comment: What values count, as an example with an array: http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: I have looked at using `memory_get_usage()`, didn't really work all that well. @hakre, interesting article. Thanks for the link. I'll have to read it thoroughly.